# Problema con auto incremental (IDENTITY) SQLSERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server, identity

primero que todo Esto lo estoy trabajando con C# y SQL SERVER.

mi problema es el siguiente:

Cuando creo una tabla y su pk es un dentity asi:

```
CREATE TABLE carro
(
id BIGINT IDENTITY  NOT NULL,
nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

cada vez que creo un nuevo registro el incremente de uno en uno sin ningun problema pero si elimino un registro:

```
delete from carro where nombre='nombre 2'
```

El elimina perfectamente el registro pero los **id** se pierde el orden ya que suponiendo tenemos **3 registros** y eliminamos el **segundo** entonces los datos quedan asi:

```
1 nombre1
3 nombre3
```

¿que puedo hacer para que los el identity queden de nuevo ordenados?, osea asi:

```
1 nombre1
2 nombre3
```

Comment: Si buscas alguna función propia de SQLServer para que realice esa lógica que planteas lamentablemente no lo tiene. Ahora si lo que buscas es crear alguna función o Trigger que lo realice no hay ningun problema, solo ten en cuenta que esto ocasionaría un trabajo exigente para el gestor ya que tendría que actualizar la clave de cada uno de los registros que viene después de elemento eliminado.

Comment: Lo que dices es otras palabras es que, ¿no es practico?.

Comment: Ademas de que tiene que reiniciar la clave para volver a insertar otra vez la ultima que se haya generado, obvio teniendo en cuenta que los registros que pudiesen almacenarse serian miles o Millones(hipotéticamente)

Comment: Entiendo, en realidad buscaba eso la "funcion o metodo" , pero si no existe pensaba hacer uso de un trigger para que lo hiciera cada vez que se eliminara algun registro aunque ya con lo que me dices me cuestiono que tan necesario es.....ya que la clave sigue siendo unica.... gracias ^^

Comment: Digamos que es eficaz, pero para nada eficiente... Perdón por la pregunta, pero cual seria la necesidad de hacer eso??

Comment: No es como tal una necesidad, era mas una inquietud porque al eliminar productos habian saltos de registro en registro y me parece que no deberia ser asi ya que queria que fuera incremental, Pero la integridad de las primary key sigue estando asi que creo no lo cambiare a menos de que alguien proponga algo logico.

Comment: Creo que pensandolo bien podria hacer ese arreglo de forma periodica asi lo hago cada X tiempo y asi no sobrecargo el sistema y arreglo el orden, GRACIAS jajajajaja me ayudaste mucho :p .

Comment: No. No debes arreglar esos. Nunca. No tiene ningun sentido. El id es una forma de identificar una linea. No debe ser parte de tu sistema y tampoco deben importarte los agujeros. Si es importante, entonces algo en tu sistema esta mal.

Comment: El id importa por su iniquicidad pero no por mas, pero ya con lo que me dices veo que no es necesario en lo mas minimo, muchas gracias por su ayuda. (¿podrias votar positivamente la pregunta?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer, en general no es necesario, y además no es recomendable porque puede dar lugar a errores y a bloqueos en la tabla.
Si de todas formas lo quieres hacer, se puede resolver así:

```
declare @max bigint = (select max(id) from carro)

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[carro]', RESEED, @max);
GO
```